# Client side Logging on client machine

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have Service Request .Net Web Application which is deployed on Server and will be used by 200+ Agent  so I want to write the log of client side on client machine(end user computer) there will be 5000 request everyday and I want to log some step of each request, as I know we can't write on client machine, but is there any way to do that?

Comment: Your IIS user should have a space where it can write logs.You will have permissions to some folder. Your question is very confusing.

Comment: I want to write the log on Client system not on server

Comment: @Dedu even after your edit, you are saying the same thing. You do not provide us with more info. What is the client for example? How do you think this should be implemented? You should almost always log to the server. Not on the client. What do you expect to fail on the client? Javascript? I hope this makes sense.